# Convert string to nested tuple : Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a string which looks like this:

```
a = '((1,2),(2,3))'
```

and I want to access it such that:

```
a[0] = (1,2)
a[0][1] = 2
```

I'd like to have it in a nested tuple form.

However nothing I do seems to work.

If it weren't a string, it works. However I am getting a string input from another source and that is why I am trying to do something like this.

```
a = ((1,2),(2,3))
print a[0][1]
# prints 2 ..it works fine
```

EDIT:
I am sorry if I oversimplified my question. My actual data looks like:

```
a = '((243, SEA, ATL, 2013-08-12 05:50:00), (243, ATL, LAX, 2013-08-22 12:30:00),(243, LAX, SEA, 2013-05-29 18:10:00))'
```

This is a string I am reading. and I would like to split it by brackets (),() so that I can sort my data chronologically and rearrange it.

any ideas on how to go about it?

the liteal_eval does indeed work on the sample data I posted earlier. But it doesnt work for the above case.

The way I'm doing it now is : 
by replacing '),(' with ';'
and removing all brackets '(',')'
and then splitting by ';'

Is there a faster/better way?

Comment: Why doesn't the `literal_eval` work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the data in one list  use re:

```
a = '((243, SEA, ATL, 2013-08-12 05:50:00), (243, ATL, LAX, 2013-08-22 12:30:00),(243, LAX, SEA, 2013-05-29 18:10:00))'

import re

print re.findall("([^(]*)\)", a[1:-1])
['243, SEA, ATL, 2013-08-12 05:50:00', '243, ATL, LAX, 2013-08-22 12:30:00', '243, LAX, SEA, 2013-05-29 18:10:00']
```

Comment: While I did find a roundabout messy way of doing it, your solution works like a charm. thanks its much more cleaner and compact.

Answer (score 7):

`ast` module's [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) method is what you are looking for:

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = '((1,2),(2,3))'
>>> b = ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> b[0]
(1, 2)
>>> b[0][1]
2
```

Comment: how about `a = '((1,2),(2,abc))'`, which should become `((1,2), (2,'abc'))` - is there a way to fall back to string for non-numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this one:

```
for row in data.split('), ('):
   for field in (f.strip() for f in row.split(',')):
      print field
```

If the data has commas, or embedded UTF8, consider using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. It's much smarter, and is able to handle quoting and other types of edge cases.